# Jackson JSON Views ignored

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to use Jackson2.0.0 with Spring3.1 so that I can use the jackson-Module-Hibernate. I have followed the steps as described here http://blog.pastelstudios.com/2012/03/12/spring-3-1-hibernate-4-jackson-module-hibernate/. All this seems to work fine, but when I try using JSON Views so that the JSON contains only the fields in the view it does not work.

The active view is always null. How do make the view active? I have tried for a day now with no luck...any help at all will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is the relavant code.

Here is the Mapper

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module;

public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
    Hibernate4Module hm = new Hibernate4Module();
    registerModule(hm);  
    hm.configure(Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, true);
}
```

}

Here is the view class

```
public class DiffViews {
 public static class Public { }
```

}

Here is the POJO where I use the view

```
 @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
 @Entity
 public class Premium implements java.io.Serializable {

@JsonView(DiffViews.Public.class)
private String sequence;
@JsonView(DiffViews.Public.class)

@Column(name = "SEQUENCE", nullable = false, length = 4)
public String getSequence() {
    return this.sequence;
}

public void setSequence(String sequence) {
    this.sequence = sequence;
}

@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

)

In my spring controller

```
@RequestMapping("/cartonPremium")
public void listAll(
        @RequestParam("page") int page, @RequestParam("rows") int maxResults, 
        @RequestParam("sidx") String sortKey, @RequestParam("sord") String sortOrder, HttpServletResponse response) {

    HibernateAwareObjectMapper mapper = new HibernateAwareObjectMapper();
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_CHAR_ARRAYS_AS_JSON_ARRAYS);
    mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION );

    JqgridResponse<Premium> gridResponse = new JqgridResponse<Premium>();
    gridResponse.setRows(premiumList);
    gridResponse.setRecords(""+premiumList.size());
    gridResponse.setTotal(""+premiumList.size());
    gridResponse.setPage(""+page);      

    try {
        ObjectWriter objWriter= mapper.writerWithView(DiffViews.Public.class);
        Class<?> xxx = mapper.getSerializationConfig().getActiveView();
        objWriter.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), gridResponse);
        //mapper.writerWithView(DiffViews.Public.class).writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), gridResponse);
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My spring config

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>    
        <bean class="com.creata.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">        
            <property name="objectMapper">            
                <bean class="com.creata.json.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />        
            </property>    
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: +1 for how to use writerWithView  and response outputstream

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found my error... I was returning my domain POJO in a wrapper called JqgridResponse and I had not added the @JsonView annotation on the fields in this wrapper class. So all is good the json view is not getting ignored.